# How to compair the length of 2 arrays

Tags: php, arrays

I'm looking for a simple way to match 2 arrys and see if they have the same length or not.

```
// 4 items    
$array_1 = array("foo","bar","hello","world");  

// 3 items          
$array_2 = array("boo","key","value");

// example
if(is_array_length_same($array_1, $array_2)){
   echo 'yes';
}else{
   // the example would return this
   echo 'no';
}
```

The example above would return a false as the number items in the array are not the same.

How can I check this ?

Comment: `if (count($array_1) == count($array_2))`.... see the [php docs](http://php.net/manual/en/function.count.php)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A very simple way to do this is to create a count for each array and then run an if statement checking whether or not they are the same

```
// array 1
$array_1 = array("foo","bar","hello","world");  

// array 2         
$array_2 = array("boo","key","value",);

// count first array
$count_array1 = count($array_1);

// count second array
$count_array2 = count($array_2);

// echo yes if the same OR no if not the same
echo ($count_array1 == $count_array2) ? "yes" : "No";
```